# ネットワーク関連のコマンドが使えない docker コンテナ内からホストのIPアドレスが知りたい

Tags: linux, docker

docker 上からホストのIPが知りたいです

```
Linux docker_mysqldb 5.10.47-linuxkit #1 SMP Sat Jul 3 21:51:47 UTC 2021 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

uname はこれです

host には名前では host.docker.internal でアクセスできるんですが

[ドキュメント](https://docs.docker.jp/docker-for-mac/networking.html)を見ると

> ホストの IP アドレスは変動します（あるいは、ネットワークへの接続がありません）。18.03 よりも前は、特定の DNS 名 host.docker.internal での接続を推奨していました。これはホスト上で内部の IP アドレスで名前解決します。

となっていてアドレスが固定ではないようです

ping や nslookup とかも何もはいってないんですが何もインストールせずに知る方法はないでしょうか

---

```
root@docker_mysqldb:/# ipconfig getifaddr en0
bash: ipconfig: command not found
root@docker_mysqldb:/# ifconfig
bash: ifconfig: command not found
root@docker_mysqldb:/# ip route
bash: ip: command not found
root@docker_mysqldb:/# /sbin/ip route
bash: /sbin/ip: No such file or directory
```

このあたりのコマンドがことごとく入っていません

Dockerfile も不明で昔作られた image だけがある状態です

Comment: 参考: [How to get the IP address of the docker host from inside a docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22944631)

Comment: `uname` はカーネル関連の情報を確認するコマンドですし、`ipconfig` は Windows のコマンドです。

Comment: > カーネル関連の情報を確認するコマンド OS情報で入ってるコマンドやみるべき etc の場所が違う可能性があるので一応はった次第です。> ipconfig は Windows のコマンドです　そうなんですね　はっていただいたリンクの２番目の回答にあったので一応うってみましたがだめでした。

Comment: 単に `root` の `PATH` が不正というか故意に `/sbin` 系を抜いているだけかもしれないです。